# Save HTML 5 camvas image to server

Tags: javascript, html

I need to save my canvas data with id='area' as an image to my server in folder /uploads with javascript.

I tried to display image in browser with window.open(canvas.toDataURL("image/png")); but browser displays blank screen

Comment: Not nearly clear enough. Please don't ask questions without making clear what steps you've taken to solve the problem and specific details about what trouble you're having. SO is not here to solve your problems for you, we're here to help.

Comment: try permadi.com/blog/2010/10/html5-saving-canvas-image-data-using-php-and-ajax/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use the `toDataURL()`

**Note** : The toDataURL() method requires that any images drawn onto the canvas are hosted on a web server with the same domain as the code executing it.  If this condition is not met, a SECURITY_ERR exception is thrown.

for example

```
 <body>
    <canvas id="myCanvas" width="578" height="200" style="display:none;"></canvas>
    <img id="canvasImg" style="border:1px solid #9C9898;" alt="Right click to save me!">
    <script>
      var canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
      var context = canvas.getContext('2d');

      // draw cloud
      context.beginPath();
      context.moveTo(170, 80);
      context.bezierCurveTo(130, 100, 130, 150, 230, 150);
      context.bezierCurveTo(250, 180, 320, 180, 340, 150);
      context.bezierCurveTo(420, 150, 420, 120, 390, 100);
      context.bezierCurveTo(430, 40, 370, 30, 340, 50);
      context.bezierCurveTo(320, 5, 250, 20, 250, 50);
      context.bezierCurveTo(200, 5, 150, 20, 170, 80);
      context.closePath();
      context.lineWidth = 5;
      context.fillStyle = '#8ED6FF';
      context.fill();
      context.strokeStyle = '#0000ff';
      context.stroke();

      // save canvas image as data url (png format by default)
      var dataURL = canvas.toDataURL();

      // set canvasImg image src to dataURL
      // so it can be saved as an image
      document.getElementById('canvasImg').src = dataURL;

    </script>
  </body>
```

Answer (score 0):

I actually solved this problem in a earlier project of mine.

And bout security between user/server and such this approach bypasses it, as i hit the possible problem mentioned in another answer here.

This might be a clumsy way to do it but atleast it works, and no im not allowed to post the code based on some legal thingy ma bob.

**On Client:**

What you can do is to have the user click a button to activate a async postback then before the postback is ran translate your canvas content into a image in the format of your choosing and then translate it into a base64 string and place it onto a hidden textbox and send the content of the textbox to your server just like you would a regular registration form.

**On Server:**

convert your newly aquired base64 string back into a picture of the same format as you created it in on client side, and save it.